# Android: Adding `interpolator` not making any difference to animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, interpolation

I am using the the noted [YOYO](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations) animation library to give animation to my views. I have been using it for a while without any issues but now when I am trying to set `interpolator` to my animation, the resulted animation is not changing. The view is still animating as it animated without `interpolator`.

Am I doing anything wrong in the code?

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInRight)
                .duration(250)
                .interpolate(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                .playOn(searchTags);
```

I even tried adding a **huge** `factor` of `100` to the interpolator like in the code below but no success

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInRight)
                .duration(250)
                .interpolate(new DecelerateInterpolator(100)) //factor 100
                .playOn(searchTags);
```

searchTags in xml

```
<me.gujun.android.taggroup.TagGroup
                        android:id="@+id/group_search_tags"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/TagGroup.Large"
                        app:atg_isAppendMode="true"/>
```

I though this problem might be with this tag view, which I have added through a library, but `interpolator` is not working even with my `recyclerView` animation.

Is there any problem with my code or anything else?

Comment: For negative votes, please comment the reason.

Comment: Are you using an old version perhaps? https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations/issues/30

Comment: @DanielZolnai I am using 1.1.3, the one mentioned on their homepage, guess thats the latest